# Show that $[0,\frac{1}{2})$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

A set of lecture notes that I am reading uses in a counterexample the fact that "$[0,\frac{1}{2})$ is open in $[0,1)$ but not in the set $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$". I am struggling to see why the second point is true. As $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is homomorphic to $[0,1)$ then for any $x\in [0,\frac{1}{2})$ you should be able to find an open ball around it that is contained in this set. I just can't see why the second point is true, perhaps I am misunderstanding what $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is.

Comment: How do you define $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ as a topological space?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}=\{\mathbb{Z}+r:r\in[0,1)\}$

Comment: That is the quotient group $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ (i.e. the algebraic quotient, not the topological quotient).  What is the topology?  It _feels_ like your $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is the circle, and your $[0,1/2)$ is a semicircle with one endpoint included.  In that case, the endpoint that is included isn't interior.

Comment: I'm new to this course, so I am still a little confused. What is the difference between thinking about it topologically and as a quotient group? And how do you know to think about this space as a circle instead of an interval or a line?

Comment: *As $\mathbb R / \mathbb Z$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1)$* ----- Stop right there and fix that. $\mathbb R / \mathbb Z$ is not homeomorphic to $[0,1)$.

Comment: @uygug seeing the topological quotient means to see the topology in the space (that would be a topology induce by the quotient) let the proyection be $\pi: \mathbb{R} \to : \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ then $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is open if $\pi^{-1}(A)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @uygug Its about notation. When writing $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ as group quotient we think of quotient of $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to the relation $x\sim y$ iff $x-y\in\mathbb{Z}$, but this could just as well be interpreted as $x\sim y$ iff $x = y$ or $x, y\in \mathbb{Z}$. The latter being a special instance of quotiening a topological space $X$ by its subspace $A$. Thats why its a bit confusing and should always be specified.

Comment: Also: "How do you know to think of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ as circle?", you simply observe that it is a circle, since the surjection $\mathbb{R}\to S^1$ given by $t\mapsto \exp(2i\pi t)$ is a quotient map, so it induces a topological group isomorphism from $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ to $S^1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us denote $Y := \mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Z}$ and denote by $\pi : \mathbb{R} \to Y$ the canonical projection. I assume we endow $Y$ with the standard quotient topology, i.e. $U \subseteq Y$ is open if and only if $\pi^{-1}(U) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open. In our case, if $U := [0, \frac{1}{2}),$ then $V := \pi^{-1}(U) = \mathbb{Z} + U = \cup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} [n, n + \frac{1}{2}).$ Clearly then, $0 \in \pi^{-1}(U),$ but there is no open neighbourhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$ fully contained in $V,$ so $0$ is not an interior point, hence $V$ is not open. In fact, none of the integers in $V$ are interior points. I hope this helps. :)